# How to change width of inline toolbar of CKEDITOR?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Can the width of the inline toolbar changed to a fixed width?

`config.width=400;` doesn't work for an inline toolbar.

Comment: which width you want to make fixed.? only the top tool bar or the whole ckeditor.?

Comment: only top toolbar, only top toolbar is visible for inline ckeditor

Answer (score 2):

The geometry of the inline toolbar can be adjusted using CSS.

The toolbar is built on top of [Floating Space](http://ckeditor.com/addon/floatingspace) plugin, which can be accessed via `.cke_float` class or [`#cke_{editor.name}`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-property-name) id attribute.

Inside the the Floating Space panel resides the `top` space of the editor (it holds the toolbar), which has `.cke_top` class and can be accessed with JS `CKEDITOR.instances.{name}.ui.space( 'top' )`.

Long story short, there are 3 different CSS approaches, and each one of them should do the trick:

```
body .cke_top,
body .cke_float,
#cke_{editor.name} {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Note: Used `body` to increase the specificity of the selector.

Yet another note: You can do the same with JS and [CKEditor API](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element-method-setStyle):

```
CKEDITOR.instances.{name}.ui.space( 'top' ).setStyle( 'width', '100px' )
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using CSS for it?

```
.cke_toolbar {
    width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.